# Spectral theorem for unbounded self-adjoint (hermitian) operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space, resource-recommendations

It is my understanding that in quantum mechanics we use [self-adjoint operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator) (that is an axiom of the theory). This operators can be either bounded or unbounded, being the latter the more general case.

Has the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) had been proven for the unbounded case?  And if so, what references discuss this?

Comment: Yes it has.  The wikipedia entry on the [Spectral Theorem (General Self-adjoint Operators)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#General_self-adjoint_operators) references Section 10.1 of *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians* by Brian Hall.

Comment: If you'd prefer a free video reference, [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPHpioiCDoM) (and the ones preceding it) by Frederic Schuller does an excellent job.

Answer (score 1):

The original source of the spectral theorem for unbounded self-adjoint operators was John von Neumann, who was a student of Hilbert. His formulation and proof can be found in the English translation *Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics*.

von Neumann uses the suggestive notation$$
H=\int \lambda \, \mathrm{d}{E \left( \lambda \right)}$$ for his spectral integral. von Neumann discusses the difference between symmetric operators and self-adjoint operators; he formulates abstract boundary conditions and discusses how to obtain a self-adjoint operator from the adjoint of a symmetric operator by imposing such conditions.

von Neumann's treatment is the original source and readable.